# Linear Interpolation of Scattered 2D Data

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, interpolation

So I have some irregularly spaced data that I want to interpolate onto a regular grid. (I want to do exactly [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3864899/resampling-irregularly-spaced-data-to-a-regular-grid-in-python/3867302#3867302) but in Java) Here's a picture:

[image: Scattered Data for Interpolation]

Basically I have the x and y coordinates of each point and a z value associated with each point and I want to interpolate between them and fill in the center of my image.

What is the best way to do this using Java? Is there a built in 2D interpolation library I can use or should I try a "roll my own" approach?

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14341369/java-2d-weighted-data-interpolation) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23671015/bilinear-interpolation-of-an-array-c-sharp?rq=1) also seem to be trying to do about what I am but their answers don't quite apply.

[Someone else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10883357/interpolating-irregularly-located-data-to?rq=1) with the same problem but no solution.

Note: I am using JavaFX-2 so if I could somehow use their `Interpolator` class that'd be great.

.
.
**EDIT:**
If anyone stumbles upon this and wants to know what I ended up using, it was a Delaunay Triangulation implementation from BGU:
[**Main Site**](http://www.cs.bgu.ac.il/%7Ebenmoshe/DT/Delaunay%20Triangulation%20in%20Java.htm)
[**Code API**](http://www.cs.bgu.ac.il/%7Ebenmoshe/DT/doc/index.html)

Comment: Do I understand your question right?: You have a set of points (x, y, z) and you want to to create an area around this points where the fillcolor depends of the z value and should interpolated between the points?

Comment: @Vertex Yep, sounds about right

Answer (score 2):

If linear interpolation is sufficient, I suggest you to use a 3d mesh with Gouraud Shading for drawing:

1. Convert the 2d point cloud to a mesh (you can google for existing algorithms)
2. Mapping the z value of each point to the vertex' color
3. Using Gouraud Shading to enable linear interpolation between the vertex colors
4. Creating a camera on top to the mesh and using a othonormal projection (to avoid perspective)

You say that you can use JavaFX. JavaFX supports 3d scenes and you can build your own meshes. But looking into the JavaDoc of TriangleMesh, I can't find any method to set the vertex color I found only a method to set the (x,y,z) and (u,v) (texture coordinates) coordinates.

Comment: It looks like that's only available in JavaFX 8. I only have JavaFX 2 =/

Comment: There are other 3d frameworks for Java like [jMonkEyengine](http://jmonkeyengine.org/). See [Custom Mesh Shapes](http://hub.jmonkeyengine.org/wiki/doku.php/jme3:advanced:custom_meshes#examplevertex_colors) for setting vertex colors.

Comment: I'm really hoping to find an easy way to do this using standard Java libraries